# ',' at </l1> error in visual studio code.This is the code

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { MenuItems } from './MenuItems';

class Navbar extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <nav class-name="NavbarItems">
                <h1 class-name="navbar-logo">React<i className="fab fa-react"></i></h1>
                <div class-name="menu-icon">


                </div>
                <ul>
                    {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
                        return( <li key={index}>
                            <a class-name={item.cName} href={item.url}>
                                {item.title}
                            </a>
                        </li>)}}
                </ul>

            </nav>
        )
    }

}

export default Navbar
```

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: ',' expected...

Comment: From `<ul>{ManuItems...`, count your braces: `{,(,(,),{,(,{,},{,},{,},{,},),},}`, 6 `{`, 3 `(`, 2 `)`, and 6 `}`; looks like you're missing a `)` in there somewhere, likely `))}}` at the end. Also, your error says `</l1>`, but that isn't in your code... Did you type that error message or paste it?

Comment: still doesn't work if i put ))}}

Comment: Same error or different? Do you have a linter installed in your IDE? We're gonna need more details, a "still doesn't work" message is not useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Missing `)` in map

```
{MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
                        return( 
                        <li key={index}>
                            <a class-name={item.cName} href={item.url}>
                                {item.title}
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        ) 
                     }
                  )
               }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have syntax issue near map function.

Comment: Unless you can clearly identify this syntax issue and provide a code fix, this is at best a comment. Also, for syntax errors, identify them in a comment (when you have the reputation), then flag to close as such (again, when you have the reputation). In the meantime, please don't misuse the answers section.

Comment: thanks for your feedback I'm new but keep in mind these points

Comment: No problem. We were all new once   Just make sure to put a little more effort into your answers and they won't be downvoted.